# docker push requires exactly 1 argument. docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG] Push an image or a repository to a registry

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, dockerhub

I'm trying to create a CI/CD pipeline to push to Docker Hub from my bitbucket repository. The build is successful up to a point where I get the following error:
[error when pushing to docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHU3l.png)

```
"docker push" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker push --help'.
Usage:  docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]
Push an image or a repository to a registry
```

Also, here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script: 
          # build the Docker image (this will use the Dockerfile in the root of the repo)
          - docker build -f docker/workspace/Dockerfile .
          # authenticate with the Docker Hub registry
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          # push the new Docker image to the Docker registry
          - docker push chatapp/monorepo:version1.1 .
```

Am I missing something in the `.yml` file? Is my `image` name something that needs a change? I'm new to pipelines and can't seem to find the error.

Comment: Remove the ` .` at the end of `docker push chatapp/monorepo:version1.1 .` like `docker push chatapp/monorepo:version1.1`

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't tagging the image during the build (e.g. docker build -t "chatapp/monorepo:version1.1" -f docker/workspace/Dockerfile .` ? How does Docker know that the tag you want to push refers to the image you just built?

Comment: @daveruinseverything, first off you're my savior. After 135 commits, I could do it finally. I did that plus, I created an access token for my local PC. It worked. Thank you so much.